# Crystax NDK Boost Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

Долго мучался в Андроид студии запустить проэкт nativeActivity с использованием Crystax NDK. Однако столкнулся с ошибками сборки, и запустить проэкт так и не удалось. Узнав о кросплатформенности Visual Studio 2015, решил перебраться из андроид студии в визуал. Как ни странно, пример запустить удалось, уже с Crystax NDK.
Но когда я полез в исходный код, и попытался использовать BOOST, студия меня послала куда подальше. Не видит она этой библиотеки, скорее всего как и остальных libpng... Как же подключить все возможности Crystax NDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio не использует NDK build system, поэтому для нее надо прописывать все пути в настройках проекта самостоятельно. Например, для CrystaX NDK 10.3.1 надо прописать пути к Boost header-ам как `$(VS_NdkRoot)\sources\boost\1.59.0\include`, а также добавить копирование Boost библиотек в Pre-link step по аналогии с копированием libcrystax: `copy /b /y "$(VS_NdkRoot)\sources\boost\1.59.0\libs\$(TargetArchAbi)\gnu-5\libboost_*.a" "$(TargetDir)"`

Comment: Увы, но почему то прописал пути, а все равно не хочет использовать команды boost. И в корневые пути добавил, и в дополнительные. Прописывал $(VS_NdkRoot)\sources\boost\1.59.0\include в настройках каталогов VС++ - Каталоги включения; также прописал в дополнительных каталогах включаемых файлов. Та же беда

Comment: Очевидно, что вы делаете что-то неверно. Все заголовочные файлы есть, библиотеки тоже. Значит, если не получается скомпилировать, либо пути указаны неверно, либо не в тех местах, где нужно. Более осмысленно ответить смогу, если предоставите полный build log.

Comment: Огромная благодарность Вам, Дмитрий, за проделанную работу и за помощь. Да, я в настройках активити добавлял, а нужно было в Library.